# Incompressiblity and speed of sound

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have read that usually if the speed of a fluid is much lower than the speed of sound (in that medium) then it can be treated as an incompressible fluid.

Where does this condition come from?

Is it possible to show it from the Navier-Stokes equation?

Comment: Can you define 'speed of a fluid'?

Comment: the $\mathbf{u}$ that appears on the LHS of the N-S equation, well its magnitude actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flows in which the maximum [Mach number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_number) is less than 0.3 are usually assumed to be incompressible.

Consider gas at rest with density $\rho_0$ that is then accelerated [isentropically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isentropic_process) to Mach number $M$. The density of the gas will change in this new state and is given by:

$$\frac{\rho_0}{\rho} = \left(1 + \frac{\gamma-1}{2}M^2\right)^{1/(\gamma-1)}$$

As it turns out, in air $M \approx 0.3 \rightarrow \rho_0/\rho = 0.95$ and it is then assumed for practical purposes that if the density changes by no more than 5% the flow can be assumed to be incompressible.

Comment: where does this equation come from?

Comment: @Harold These two pages from NASA go through the derivation (although in very poor-looking notation) of the equation above: [isentropic flow equations](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/isentrop.html) and [derivation](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/isndrv.html). Basically it is the result of applying the first and second laws of thermodynamics for a gas.

Comment: When I have more time I will reproduce that derivation here.